# Segmentation fault. I don't know how to do this

Tags: segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I'm having this error, and I have been all the evening on it.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004019fe in TPoro::Color (this=0x7fffffffde40, 
    xx=0x401e9e "aZUL") at lib/tporo.cpp:84
84                  xx[i] = xx[i] + 'a' - 'A';
```

This is the function on question (it receive a *char and it has to lower case it and copy to color) :

```
void
TPoro::Color(char * xx){

    if (xx != NULL){

        delete color;
        color =  new char[strlen(xx) + 1];


        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(xx) - 2 ; i++)
        {
            if((xx[i] <= 'Z') && (xx[i] >= 'A')){

                xx[i] = xx[i] + 'a' - 'A';// HERE IS THE ERRORR!!

            }
        }

        strcpy(color, xx);
    }else{
        delete color;
        color=NULL;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Have you tried walking through this in `gdb`? Setting a breakpoint? Do you know the value of `i` when it fails? Are you sure the string `xx` is writable (in other words, in your call to TPoro::Color do you have to cast the thing from a const char * to a char *)?

Comment: the values are right, the problem is with doing an assignment of the pointer with another pointer.

Comment: `the values are right` Yes, sure, but... what are they? Does it fail on the first iteration of the loop, or...?

Comment: yes it fails the first time when arrive to error line.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help it but stare at `this=0x7fffffffde40` which is a pretty big/magic-like number. `this` refers to the object instance with which you called this method. Are you sure it's initialized properly?

Another reason might be that 'xx' is a `const char *`, and not `char *`. Modifying data in memory marked as `const` can cause segfaults.

On a side note, you really shouldn't be using `new` and `delete` like that. Your method will always start with deleting `color` which may not be initialized when it's called. Plus, use `std::string` instead of C-styled character arrays. And please don't use `NULL`. Use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: I know that the problem is on assign a pointer to a pointer + something, but I don't know how to do it well.

Comment: A high memory address just means the object was stack-allocated.